# How to debug Alembic migrations inside VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, alembic

Say I have a migration script like this one:

```
# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'b5c9e0aac59b'
down_revision = '4658d3e26bae'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

def upgrade():
    print("hello world!")
```

And I want to place a breakpoint on the line that contains the `print` statement.

How can I configure VS Code to launch the command `alembic -n sandbox upgrade b5c9e0aac59b` (or `python -m alembic -n sandbox upgrade b5c9e0aac59b`), and use VS Code debugging features?